# What is the meaning of four popes?

Tags: meaning

Deloris, new Nun student, taking music classes to Nuns instead of Mary Lazarus, Music teacher & also Nun. so Deloris is saying each Nun should listen to other Nun while singing choir. So Mary Lazarus, who is standing beside them, reacted.

> Deloris: You must listen to each other if you're going to be a group.
>
> Mary Lazarus: I knew that.
>
> Deloris: Mary Lazarus, as soon as I walked in the door,  I knew that
>   you knew this. Now, you're somebody who's into hard work and
>   discipline, aren't you?
>
> Mary Lazarus: Of course, I'm a nun. **Four popes** now.
>
> Deloris: Four? Wow

Comment: "I have been a nun during the reigns of four popes."

Comment: What is the source? Could also be written as "For four popes now." If spoken, it could be confusing.

Answer (score 1):

Credit to StoneyB for already more or less answering this in a comment.

---

Mary Lazarus is approximating the length of time she has been a nun. She is saying that from the time she became a nun until the present, there have been four different men serving as pope.

For a similar example, a government employee might describe their tenure with "three Presidents."

Given the context, this kind of claim is meant to express that she has been a nun for a long time, and that this ought to make it obvious she knows what she's talking about.

Comment: As the quote is from sister act 2, 1993, the four popes would be John Paul II, John Paul I, Paul VI and John XXIII. Mary Lazerus has been a nun since at least 1963, (30 years)